# unrecognized set of characters in byobu

Tags: debian, byobu

I am using `byobu` on a Google Cloud instance installed with Debian 4.9.130-2. Whenever I ssh into the instance a second time after my first session's connection is broken e.g. internet got disconnected the I run the `byobu` command, my `byobu` session comes with these unrecognized set of characters as shown in the picture below. How can I get rid of them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the byobu session name.

You can disable it by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> then
*Toggle status notifications* , use the space bar to uncheck it,  then apply changes:

```
[ ] session
```

`byobu --help`:

```
session - byobu session name (only supported in byobu-tmux(1)); displayed in
the lower bar on the left in underlined black text  on  a  white  back-ground
```

Comment: Instead of F6 you mean to say F9.